# Array: remove duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an **array formula** returning an array. **The formula can not be changed**.

The result is an array containing multiple values, e.g.: `{1,2,2,4,5,1}`

I need to remove the duplicates out of the array and get an array with unique, distinct values: `{1,2,4,5}`

Is this possible on an array level?

Comment: Use google sheets! :) :P You can then wrap your array in UNIQUE() which does just that!

Comment: Unfortunately I'm tied to MS Excel due to company restrictions (not my private system I am working on).

Comment: Can you use VBA User Defined Function?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to set up using some helper columns and then collapse back to a single result? Because I don't think it will be possible to do this in a single cell, without using VBA / getting the original array formula changed.

Comment: Also - why do you want to pull it into an Array? You aren't giving enough information to answer this; it's possible you are sidestepping a solution which would get you the end product you want, because of the way you perceive the likely answer to be.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you could do this using some helper columns - but I highly doubt this is more efficient than going back to whoever gave you the array formula and asking them to adjust it:

In column A on a new sheet, starting at A2 and copied down as far as you have data, put the following formula:

```
=INDEX([ORIGINAL ARRAY FORMULA],ROW()-1)
```

This is now a representation of your array, cell by cell.

Then on B2 and copied down as lfar as you have data, put the following formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,$A$1:A1,0)),A2,"")
```

This looks at column A, and if the current row's value is present in a higher row, it ignores it and shows "". If the value is unique, it shows that value.

Finally in cell B2, put the following formula, to bring the data back up into an array - I have applied SUM to it to pick all the values into a single result, but you will need to replace this with whatever it is you want to do with the unique array. Note

```
=SUM(IFERROR(SMALL(B2:B7,row(B2:B7)-1),""))
```

As this is an Array Formula, you will need to confirm with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER, instead of just enter. Note that B2:B7 shown above will need to be replaced with B2:Bxx, where xx represents the number of data items you have in your list.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. Sorry for the delay, I was on vacation in the mean time. Currently I do not need a solution anymore as the sheet has been dropped. Your approach is nearly what I needed, but as the original question is not answered (doing this on an array level without cells) I can not mark the post as answer.

Comment: @JDC, I must say, the qualifier "doing this on an array level" is a confusing statement. What is **"on an array level"**? Do you mean to say: __"I have a formula in a cell that produces an array, and within the same formula, I want to remove the duplicates?"__. If that's the case, your qualifier should be: "within a single formula".

If the author modifies the answer to say "No, it isn't possible. But here's a workaround.", then indeed this should be marked as the accepted answer, since it both answers your question ("Is this possible?") and gives an acceptable workaround.

Answer (score -1):

Use [UNIQUEVALUES() function](http://web.archive.org/web/20111021064220/http://xcell05.free.fr/morefunc/english/valeurs.uniques.htm) from the MOREFUNC ADDON (see below)

---

**MOREFUNC ADDON**

- Morefunc Addon is a free library of 66 additional excel worksheet functions.
- [HERE](http://web.archive.org/web/20111204011358/http://xcell05.free.fr/morefunc/english) is some information (by original author; website has since been removed / abandoned, hence the WaybackMachine version)
- here is the last working [download link](http://www.freewarefiles.com/downloads_counter.php?programid=14922) I found
- here is a good [installation walk-through video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAofPm4LCRc#t=92)

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use plain Excel as this is a company system and I have no influence on what is installed. Also other people using the sheet would have to install the addon (not possible without much effort as we would have to pass the whole IT workflow, etc.). But thank you anyways for the suggestion!

Answer (score -1):

What is the formula that returns that array, maybe that can be modified.

Comment: Unfortunately not, the formula is fix and given (not by me).

Comment: @JDC Yes but you are going to have to add a new formula anyway, perhaps the new formula can be based on the old and modified to return a unique list